# parsing a text file in shell script and extract the values in a list

Tags: bash

I have a text file with below content.

```
NewFile1.txt
        Targets:
            target1
            target2
            target3
            ....... 

        Build Configurations:
            config1
            config2
            config3
            .......

        Schemes:
            schemeName1
            schemeName2 
            schemeName3
            ...........
            ...........
```

I want to parse the file and extract all the schemes and put in a list.
How can I achieve this shell script?

Comment: There are plenty of tools you could use : `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `perl`, ... [Here](https://regex101.com/r/ni1Pdg/1) is a sample regex that achieves more or less what you want, feel free to play around with it. As of now, your question is off-topic as you didn't show us any of the code you tried, nor did you tell us what tools you were using. Don't hesitate to edit your question to add additional details.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one line solution with awk.

```
awk 'p && NF {print;} /Schemes:/ {p=1}' NewFile1.txt
schemeName1
schemeName2 
schemeName3
```

pls. look after "awk vs sed" on the net, and you will see that awk will be more handy instead of sed in the most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing there will be a newline after the `schemeNameX` list :

```
sed -n '/Schemes:/,/^$/p'
```

The `-n` flag disables implicit output so we can specify `sed` only to print in a range. The start of the range is defined by `/Schemes:/` which tests this text appears somewhere in the line, while the end of the range is defined by `/^$/`, which tests that a line is empty.

This will also return the `Schemes:` line and an trailing newline, which can be discarded easily with `head` and `tail`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. This is what i need but how can i use head and tail to remove the schemes: and final line. I am new to scripting.

Comment: You can remove the first line with `tail -n +2` and the last with `head -n -1`.  Also there might be a way to do that in a single command, so maybe you accepted my answer a little quickly :) Don't hesitate to change your mind if another better answer comes !